# how to get and set tabindex in jquery

Tags: jquery

Im going to set tab index,

```
$("#DilutionFactor1_" + nCount).attr(
       'tabindex',
       $("#UnitOfMeasure" + nCount).attr('tabindex')+ 1) ;
```

but this is not working. Anyone can help me to solve this?

Comment: Seems to work for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ekqfM/) ...

Comment: are there any js errors in firebug ??

Comment: im still looking at the code,interdependancey functions are there, so it takes some time, thanx for all suggestions and answers

Comment: is this correct kanishka ..?        `$("#DilutionFactor1_" + nLine).tabindex = $("#UnitOfMeasure" + nCount).tabindex + 1;`

Comment: @MaduraHarshana hmmm , i am not sure about that :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try to use `parseInt`

```
 $("#DilutionFactor1_" + nCount).attr('tabindex',
parseInt($("#UnitOfMeasure" + nCount).attr('tabindex'))+ 1) ;
```